# Usage of X displays: make screenshot from window without showing it

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

My goal is to make screenshot from window without displaying it.

Code: All the `Xvfb`-things works with QT ([example](http://pastie.org/4572412)), but seems like I do not fully understand how to use it with GTK.

```
import gtk,webkit,gobject,sys,os,time
web=webkit.WebView()
url = 'http://google.com/'
web.open(url)
win=gtk.Window()
win.add(web)

silence_xvfb=True
display='1'
screen='0'
xvfb_timeout=3
pidfile = '/tmp/.X%s-lock' % display
redirect = '> /dev/null 2>&1'
if not silence_xvfb:
    redirect = ''
cmd = ' '.join(['Xvfb', ':'+display, '-screen', screen, '1600x1200x24', redirect])
os.system(cmd+' &')

start = time.time()
while(True):
    diff = time.time() - start
    if(diff > xvfb_timeout):
        raise SystemError("Timed-Out waiting for Xvfb to start - {0} sec".format(xvfb_timeout))
    if(os.path.isfile(pidfile)):
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(0.05)

os.putenv('DISPLAY', ':%s' % display)

def drawWindow(win):
    width, height = win.get_size()
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8, width, height)

    screenshot = pixbuf.get_from_drawable(win.window, win.get_colormap(), 
                                          0, 0, 0, 0, width, height)

    screenshot.save('screenshot.png', 'png')
    print 'screenshot saved'

win.show_all()
gobject.timeout_add(5000, drawWindow, win)
gtk.main()
```

Comment: WHat has this with Python to do? Setting DISPLAY as environment variables works *all* and *everywhere* for all X11 applications - including every GTK based application.

Comment: Exactly the same way. Set your DISPLAY variable. It's an [X level thing](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/X.7.html) and has nothing to do with gtk or QT.

Comment: You might want to consider using something like [`xwd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xwd) to do the screen capturing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All X11-based code (Qt, KDE, gtk, wxWindows, ...) uses the `DISPLAY` variable to define which display to use. [See the docs](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/X.7.html) for details.

You problem is that the variable is examined once per process at the time of the first X11 call (more or less).

So in your case, you create a window and then you try to set the `DISPLAY` variable. X11 can't move existing windows from one instance to another.

What you need to do is split the code above into two processes. One starts `Xvfb` and sets the `DISPLAY` variable and the other renders the UI.

Comment: thanks:) I already get it from comments, and now I edited my question for... *read your edited post, and check one thing* well, may be, Ill try it now. but why it does not work if I simply put creation of window below the setting of environment var?